# Why I am not seeing HTTP 304 response codes in my Apache logs?

Tags: apache, cache, logging, 304-not-modified

Why I am not seeing HTTP 304 response code in my Apache logs even though my webpages are sending them? I've checked this in Chrome console:

[image]

My goal is to see which browsers are successfully using ETag header which I am sending with every page. As I said, I can see that in Chrome but not in server logs. Now I suspect that maybe headers are not logged at all, but I have to ask you about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default logging configuration of Apache 2, HTTP `304` responses should be logged in **access logs** (and not in error logs).

Here is an anonymized example of what I have in my `access.log` (with the default logging configuration):

`127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2020:20:49:45 +0200] "GET /image.png HTTP/1.1" 304 515 "http://www.example.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:67.0) Gecko/67.0 Firefox/67.0"`

Comment: thanks, actually it showed in my logs too, it was due to a delay probably because my site is on the shared hosting.

Comment: @DejanDozet, Yes, for example, I have a shared hosting on which logs are delayed by about 5 min.